# Laravel : How to check if relation have rows inside relation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This:

```
//model
public function logo(){
    $logo = $this->belongsTo(Media::class, 'image_id');
    echo $logo->count();
}

//template
echo $product->logo;
```

gives me output 32, but there is only one row. If I run this outside relation :

```
//model
public function logo(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Media::class, 'image_id');
}

//template
echo $product->logo()->count();
```

output is 1. How to check how many rows have relation inside relation ?

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? The non-technical part. What's the model name?

Comment: I want to know how many rows relation have. Model name is Product.

Comment: You should elaborate your question for better answers

Answer (score 0):

Try Product::with('logo')->first(); // or do Product::findOrFail($id) for a specific product and based on that query, try `count($model->relationMethodName)` and see if you will get the number you are looking for.

Comment: not working, because relation is returned not collection.